# Pre Cumulative update process

Tags: 2010, cumulative-update

Guys this is the first time im installing a sp2010 CU.  I would like to know what i need to do before applying this update to our servers.  Specifically what do i need to backup before i apply and any other steps.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recommends you backup and document the entire environment:
[Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806331%28office.14%29.aspx)

I'm guessing you were after a more "personal experience" kind of information but I thought I'd put the link here in case you hadn't read it.